# Failed to execute script due to unhandled expression: Cannot load AutoItX from path

Tags: python, error-handling, pyinstaller, exe, autoit

I am compiling my python code into an exe using **pyinstaller** It all goes well until i actually run the exe where I get this error from my library **autoit**.

[image]

I do have image files and folders in the directory which the code relies on too if that helps.

this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pynput
import time
import autoit
import pyautogui

import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'tesseract\tesseract.exe'

keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

backpack = cv2.imread("Icons/backpack.png")
giftshop = (816, 845)
plus = (895, 700)
yes = (1050, 660)
needs = (938, 50)
nursery = (814, 714)
supermarket = (752, 804)
menu = (32, 20)
accesoryshop = (750, 755)
vehicle = (810, 805)
stroller = (810, 755)

tpTime = 4

need = ''

def key(key, sec, diagonal='none'):
    if(diagonal == 'none'):
        if(key == 'w' or key == 's' or key == 'a' or key == 'd'):
            keyboard.press(key)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            keyboard.release(key)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(key)
        print('pressed', key, 'for', sec)
        time.sleep(sec)
        keyboard.release(key)
        print('released', key, 'after', sec)
    elif(diagonal == 'left'):
        keyboard.press(key)
        keyboard.press('a')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release(key)
        keyboard.release('a')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(key)
        keyboard.press('a')
        time.sleep(sec)
        keyboard.release(key)
        keyboard.release('a')
    else:
        keyboard.press(key)
        keyboard.press('d')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.release(key)
        keyboard.release('d')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press(key)
        keyboard.press('d')
        time.sleep(sec)
        keyboard.release(key)
        keyboard.release('d')

def click(button):
    autoit.mouse_click("left", button[0], button[1])
```

this is not my full code just the snippet that matters